# Why this F# code with member constraint does not compile?

Tags: f#, constraints, member

For me it seems that compiler has all information for that point, but I get error message. Why?

```
let inline getLength< ^a when ^a : (member Length : int ) > (x: ^a) = x.Length
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call a member required by a static constraint, you need to use a more involved syntax:

```
let inline getLength< ^a when ^a : (member Length : int ) > (x: ^a) = 
  (^a : (member Length : int) x)
```

This is a bit ugly - which I think emphasizes the point that static member constraints are not the primary way of achieving things (often, you can use e.g. interfaces or other more usual techniques instead).

Also, if you are interested mainly in mathematical code, then you can just use standard operators and functions (together with a few primitives in `LanguagePrimitives`) and you won't have to invoke members explicitly.

Comment: So I have to use constraint invocation expression every time I want to access member specified in constrain?

Comment: Yes, a priori you do. Though, I suppose you are calling Length on an array? at which point, you could just write `let getLength (x : 'a array) = x.Length`

Comment: @ironic - Yes, but once you define `getLength`, you can just use this function to get the length (from any other function) and the constraints will be propagated automatically. But I think @DanielFabian is actually right here and you probably just want a simple array :-)

Comment: Thanks for comments! Actually I was trying on String, but this is not important.